# How to get the screen position of the four corners of an image target using Vuforia ARCamera in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, perspective

How to find the screen position of the four corners of an image target in Vuforia for perspective transform?

"GetLocalCorners" returns an array of four corners that represent the corners of the rectangular shape. but I need image corners.

I want to get screen position(pixel) in yellow points

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you speak of `GetLocalCorners` assuming you have a `RectTransform` => You would first go through [GetWorldCorners](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.GetWorldCorners.html) then pass those through [WorldToScreenPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html)

so e.g.

```
RectTransform rectTransform = YOUR_TARGET_RECT_TRANSFORM;
var corners = new Vector3[4];
rectTransform.GetWorldCorners(corners);
var camera = Camera.main;
for(var i = 0; i < corners.Length; i++)
{
    corners[i] = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(corners[i]);
}
```

Now the `corners` are in pixel screen space.

---

If the target is actually not a `RectTransform` you would need to calculate the corners in worldspace yourself first. Might look somewhat like e.g.

```
var position = YOUR_TARGET_Transform.position;
// assuming that scale is applied to the target so that it matches with the target dimensions 
var size = YOUR_TARGET_Transform.lossyScale;
// assuming your target is by default flat on the XZ plane
// => transform.up points towards the sky by default
// if the target is actually rotated you need to adjust those
var x = YOUR_TARGET_Transform.right * size.x * 0.5f;
var z = YOUR_TARGET_Transform.forward * size.z * 0.5f;
var corners = new Vector3[4];
corners[0] = position - x - z;
corners[1] = position - x + z;
corners[2] = position + x + z;
corners[3] = position + x - z;
```

Little demo of that

```
public class TEST : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RectTransform[] images;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var position = transform.position;

        // assuming that scale is applied to the target so that it matches with the target dimensions 
        var size = transform.lossyScale;

        // assuming your target is by default flat on the XZ plane
        // => transform.up points towards the sky by default
        // if the target is actually rotated you need to adjust those
        var x = transform.right * size.x * 0.5f;
        var z = transform.forward * size.z * 0.5f;
        var corners = new Vector3[4];
        corners[0] = position - x - z;
        corners[1] = position - x + z;
        corners[2] = position + x + z;
        corners[3] = position + x - z;

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            corners[i] = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(corners[i]);

            images[i].position = (Vector2)corners[i];
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: but that "corners" is rectangular shape of game object, like bounding box. I need to find the corner of game object

Comment: @Kai you mentioned `GetLocalCorners` so it sounded like you already have a `RectTransform` to work with ... tried to add an alternative calculation at the bottom but I guess we would need more details about your target object

Comment: can you check the image I posted , I draw 4 yellow corners that I try to get.

Comment: @Kai I know .. I got that ... but I have no clue how your target object actually is composed component wise and how exactly it behaves while tracking regarding its orientation and scale etc ... currently I can only make wild assumptions ;)

Comment: and  [here is target image](https://images.app.goo.gl/3TMmoHZ9LeHb3JxPA)

Comment: @Kai ... I do not need the image / texture .. I need to know how exactly your `GameObject` looks like! What are its components attached to hit, is i further nested under other objects or at scene root level? Is it uniform scaled or does Vuforia set the actual real wold scales as separate components to the scale .... etc

Comment: I think you are right. I need to get position and orientation of image target and based on scale to calculate four corners in world position then convert it to screen position. thank you, derHugo.

Comment: Hi @Kai ,
were you able to find the answer you want, I need exactly the same

Comment: @NavidHosseini anything unclear in the answer?